# How to pass into a function an array sliced until the whole array is processed

Tags: php, arrays, logic

Sorry if the title is not that clear.

**Scenario:** I have an array with 500+ items.

**Problem:** I need to pass the items into a function which accept arrays no bigger then 20 items.

**My Solution:**

```
$sliceSize = 20;

if(count($arr) > $sliceSize) {
    for($c = 0; count($arr) - $c*$sliceSize >= 0; $c++ ) {
        $show = array_slice($arr, $c*$sliceSize, $sliceSize, true);
        if(count($show) > 0)
             the_fantastic_function($show);
    }
}
```

Is there a better, compact and more performing way to do it?

Comment: Why does that function allow only up to 20 elements? Can you not just edit the function instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_chunk`

```
$arr = array_chunk($arr, 20);
foreach($arr AS $chunk) {
    the_fantastic_function($chunk);
}
```